# Is possible to linking a function with a different name

Tags: c++, c, c++11

Well, function names are only labels to pointing starting address of a function, so can we link a function with a different name? As a example in OpenGL API functions are starting with 'gl', can we chance this to 'GL'? I have OCD, this is really hard for me.

Comment: You can write the "GL" functions yourself and call the "gl" functions from inside. That way you can use your favorite names without loss of functionality or performance.

Comment: Well you could write wrapper functions named how you want it and then just call the `gl` function in the body.

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Things have standardized names for a reason. You're talking about doing a huge amount of pointless extra work,  maybe breaking compatibility, and causing confusion in communicating with other programmers. Lots of things in life are hard.

Comment: Wow, people voting to close as "too broad"? Just because there are multiple solutions doesn't mean that you have to expand 10 pages to cover them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a better solution:

```
#define GLFunction(Function) gl##Function
```

So:

```
#define GLClearDepth GLFunction(ClearDepth)
//...
```

More bearable to see.

Answer (score 7):

Given that this is C++11, you can easily create an alias to any function that you like with the auto keyword:

```
const auto Finish = glFinish;
int main()
{
    Finish();
}
```

Using `const` informs the compiler that nothing else will modify the function pointer/alias that you've set up and that may enable better code generation.

There isn't a built-in, automated way to "rename" functions, however. Other than manually maintaining a list, one way to get a similar result would be to find a page that has every OpenGL call and do a regex search-and replace for the pattern `(gl(.+))` to `const auto \2 = \1;`, or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You could create function pointers with whatever name you want and assign the existing functions to them:

```
char *(*my_strcpy)(char *, const char *) = strcpy;
```

You could also use the preprocessor as follows if your compiler supports `__VA_ARGS__`:

```
#define my_function(...) gl_function(__VA_ARGS__)
```

The latter is probably easier to use since you don't have to know the return type or the number and type of the arguments.

While you could define the above macro as a non-function type, defining it as a function-type macro will help prevent it from being replaced in places you wouldn't want it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `#define` to rename all the functions (although I would recommend **not** doing this if you ever intend to share your code with anyone else). For example

```
#define GLClear      glClear
#define GLDrawArrays glDrawArrays
#define GLFinish     glFinish
```